# A dynamically assigned link's get variable is undefined after first 'get' call

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, get

I'm developing a library management system for my university project. Found a solution to load dynamic content inside a bootstrap 3 modal with this source.

[BOOTSTRAP 3.1 AND MODALS WITH REMOTE CONTENT](http://tutsme-webdesign.info/bootstrap-3-1-and-modals-with-remote-content/)

But when I apply it to my project as follows,

**index.php**

```
<?php if($tot_rows > 0){  ?>
   <?php do { ?>
       <div class="col-md-3 animatedbounceIn">
           <span class="product-image">
              <?php $isbnget = $rows['ISBN']; ?>
               <a href="books/view.php?bookisbn=<?php echo $isbnget;  ?>" id="bookid" data-target="#my_modal"class="bookget" data-toggle="modal"><img src="<?php echo $rows['Cover'] ?>" class="img-thumbnail product-img" alt=""></a>
            </span>
               <ul class="iteminfo">
                    <li class="animated fadeInLeftShort" data-id='1'><strong>Title: </strong><?php echo $rows['Title'] ?></li>
                    <li class="animated fadeInLeftShort" data-id='1'><strong>Category: </strong><?php echo $rows['Category'] ?></li>
                    <li class="animated fadeInLeftShort" data-id='2'><strong>Author: </strong><?php echo $rows['Author'] ?></li>
                    <li class="animated fadeInLeftShort" data-id='2'><strong>Price: </strong><?php echo $rows['Price'] ?></li>
                    <li class="animated fadeInLeftShort" data-id='3'><strong>ISBN: </strong><?php echo $rows['ISBN'] ?></li>
                    <li class="animated fadeInLeftShort" data-id='3'><strong>Copies: </strong><?php echo $rows['Copies'] ?></li>
              </ul>
        </div>
    <?php } while($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)); }else{ ?>
    <?php echo 'No Results'; }?>
   </div>
```

The `<a href="books/view.php?bookisbn=<?php echo $isbnget;?>"`... link passes the get variable(my dynamic isbn number) to the view page.

**view.php**

```
<?php   $isbn = $_GET['bookisbn'];?>
```

That variable is passed to mysql query to acquire data from database and when I click the first time the proper data (that supposed to be loaded), is loaded to the bootstrap modal properly but when I close that modal and then clicked on another link (which is supposed to be with another isbn number acquired by above index page's code)it's get variable is mentioned as 'undefined'(view.php?bookisbn=undefined) and correspondent data not loaded on the modal. The same data which was loaded from first link is shown. To load that data I have to refresh again and click it. Please help me to solve this. I'm trying to find a jquery method. I hope your suggestions to fix this. Thank you.

Comment: "then clicked on another link"  where is another link ?

Comment: all links are generated when looped the code above....  List of books with separated ISBN numbers and each links have that isbn numbers!